# jQuery.animate() with css class only, without explicit styles

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery animate I would like to operate with css classes, defined somewhere in .css file, not to have to  give all styles params to jquery.animate() explicitly.

I can create a fake (e.g. invisible) element with such a class, read its css properties and give them to jquery.animate()  - does anybody know a better way?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) provides a extension to `animate` function that allows you to animate css class.

**edit**: Example [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/)

There are also methods to **add/remove/toggle** class which you might also be interested in.

Comment: I thought this extension only provided support for additional css properties. Could you provide a link to documentation of this behaviour?

Comment: maybe it is just webkit, but i've never been that much deceived by any jq or ui functionnalities.

Comment: FYI Currently jQuery UIs addClass() doesn't work with IEs proprietary filters E.g. "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)" as it only works on scalar values... If only they polyfilled this as they do with animate..

Answer (score 6):

Weston Ruther built a similar thing using the [WebKit proposal for css transitions](http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/):

http://weston.ruter.net/projects/jquery-css-transitions/

This implementation might be useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

Check out James Padolsey's [animateToSelector](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/animateToSelector/)

> Intro: This jQuery plugin will allow
>   you to animate any element to styles
>   specified in your stylesheet. All you
>   have to do is pass a selector and the
>   plugin will look for that selector in
>   your StyleSheet and will then apply it
>   as an animation.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases you're better off using CSS transitions for this, and in old browsers the easing will simply be instant. Most animations (like fade in/out) are very trivial to implement and the browser does all the legwork for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: This link is broken now :(