# Add and remove a class with animation

Tags: jquery

I have written a script that changes the box's color in another box's hover:
http://jsfiddle.net/w5b9v/2/

How can I add animation to this transition?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could do something this way http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/fn68L/

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".wrapper div.me:last").addClass("reduce");
  $(".wrapper div.me").hover(
  function(){
     $(this).fadeTo('fast',1); //or $(this).animate({opacity:1},300/*ms*/)
     $(".wrapper div").not(this).fadeTo('fast',0.8);
  }); 
});
```

Or you can check [Animate to Class](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class) jquery plugin ;)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery .animate method animates mostly numeric properties and doesn't cover adding a subtracting a class.

If you simply want to change opacity, you can use [.fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

```
$(".wrapper div").not(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
```

The above will reduce the opacity by half.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles) provides more information, including the jQueryUI [switchClass](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/) method.  That question also suggests the [.animateToSelector](http://james.padolsey.com/demos/animateToSelector/) plugin.

Finally there is [animateToClass](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class), but that appears to simply wrap the features of .animate into a class, which means some of your non-numeric values won't work.