# Use css id to animate a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to animate a certain div using styles of a class?

Example (html):

```
<div id="nice_div"></div>
```

Css:

```
#nice_div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.animate{
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

What i would like to achieve is something like this:

```
$("#nice_div").animate(".animate");
```

Obviously this code is fictional. Is there any way to achieve something similar? Oh yeah, .animate div is not available in DOM. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Honestly man. Go read a few tutorials before asking question here simple as that. This site also has tons of similar posts.

Comment: @ppumkin I'm sincerely curious, could you post an answer / a hint to this "Simple" question? I don't think it is _that_ simple

Comment: I dont understand your question. You can either use CSS3 to animate of jQuery animate function. Are you trying to invent something in the middle? Also did you see this http://jqueryui.com/  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles

Comment: @ppumkin I think you misread the question `.animate()` just can't do what he asks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible:

```
#nice_div {
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
    -moz-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
    transition: height 1s, width 1s;


    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

$("#nice_div").addClass(".animate");
```

Comment: Magic question. What about IE7, 8? :)

Comment: Nice answer, but this isn't really workable as IE has no support for this at all.

Comment: This is obviously best solution for animating. Screw IE :) THX!

Comment: No support at all? The box gets expanded to new dimensions, so the end result is the same. I honestly don't think most IE7 and IE8 users have that web browser for an enhanced user experience, and simply wants functionality rather then eyecandy. Aslong as those users can see the content and no bugs occur, I'm satisfied.

Comment: IE Users need to upgrade. If the user is not up with times then why should it stop webdeveloeprs from using CSS3. Hence, it will force more users to goto firefox or chrome or IE9..10? if we use CSS3 everywhere and ignore the oldies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) method only accepts a map of properties to change.

It may be possible to create a map from a hidden element which has the class already applied to it, but this would be very tricky to implement as you wouldn't be able to know programmatically which styles were set from your stylesheet, and which are auto-set by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove CSS class for a particular element using jquery

```
$('#nice_div').click(function(){
this.addClass('animate');
                              });
```

You can alos remove the class using

```
$('#nice_div').removeClass('animate');
```

Comment: Well i want to use animation not just adding and removing classes.

Comment: But this will not make the change a smoothe transition, it will just instantly change from one state to another.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is not possible as jQuery `animate()` function has certain properties and we need to pass. it does not directly connect to css class.

additionally if you need to ass new class to the same element you can use `addClass()` function or `css()` function as per your requirement.

What you can try to achieve something like this is have a hidden file on page. Access the value in hidden field and concatenate the value in `animate()` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

To animate any element, such as a simple image:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123"
  style="position: relative; left: 10px;" />
```

To animate the opacity, left offset, and height of the image simultaneously:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: I think the OP knows how to normally animate with jquery, he wants to animate using a pre-defined class.