# Animate addClass + removeClass transitions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transitions

Say I have 2 boxes, one positioned in the top left hand corner of the screen using this class:

```
.position1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

and another positioned in the bottom right using this class:

```
.position2 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 100px;
}
```

Is there a simple way, using jQuery or otherwise, to:

- Slide (animate) the box in the upper left into the position of the bottom right one
- Slide (animate) the box in the bottom right into the position of the top left one

I can easily achieve this **without using an animation** by simple doing `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`... but I need the animations themselves to imitate the boxes "switching places" with each other rather than just instantaneously swapping sides.

I've looked at the jQuery animate feature but it doesn't appear, unless I'm mistaken, that you can apply a pre-defined class (and remove a pre-defined class) as an option of the animate function.

Comment: *to imitate the boxes "switching places" with each other rather than just instantaneously swapping sides.* this is overly theoretical.

Answer (score 2):

Look here: [jQuery.animate() with css class only, without explicit styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles) or here: http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/

Answer (score 1):

You can use transitions for this as well.  One problem you *may* run into with your original CSS is that you can't transition between a pixel value and initial (no property) value.

Here is a bare bones example (webkit only) of a simple transition that I believe does what your are asking for:

**CSS**

```
.changer {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
}

#one { background-color: blue; }
#two { background-color: red; }

.position1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
}

.position2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="changer position1"></div>
<div id="two" class="changer position2"></div>
```

**Javascript**  (run in unload with timeout just for a bit of delay for the sample)

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var one = document.getElementById('one');
    var two = document.getElementById('two');  

    one.classList.remove('position1');
    one.classList.add('position2');
    two.classList.remove('position2');
    two.classList.add('position1');
}, 500);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMKNP/1/)**