# Animate addition of a class through jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have:

```
<div class="button" id="button1">Click</div>
<div class="button" id="button2">Click</div>
```

and the JS

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.button').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

CSS

```
.selected {

background-color: green;

}
```

Can I 'animate' the applying of the class 'selected'? I.e on a click of the div, the background slides in from the right or fades in for example? Is there a decent plugin available that could achieve this? Is there are a CSS workaround/method?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles

Answer (score 2):

Simply use CSS3

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/JfK6N/

if you don't want to use CSS3 to support older Browsers use the done() callback of animate

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.button').removeClass('selected');
$(this).animate({
  backgroundColor: green
}, 1000, "linear", function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 for that. Use transition to background color change.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;                  
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;                 
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;   
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;          
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

Here is the example with your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mm9mV/

Comment: Thanks, do you know if you can say, "slide in from right" using css3?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want. To slide in all the buttons, or  a transition effect that's filling up the background from left to right.

Comment: No worries, I got it sorted using a background image and `-webkit-transition:background-position 0.4s ease;` and then using .addClass to change the background position.