# Transition when adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, transition

How to apply Transition when adding and remove class on this scroll js *below:*

```
lastScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll === 0){
        $(".header").removeClass("shrink");
    } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".header").addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("shrink");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

Trying to add this `({'transitionTime': 200})` when add and remove class.

Main Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/ 
Example Here: [Link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Hide-Sticky-Navbar-When-Scrolling-Down-Scroll-Up-Menu/) >>

Comment: What did you try doing? how did that work?

Comment: See this Example: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Hide-Sticky-Navbar-When-Scrolling-Down-Scroll-Up-Menu/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.animate() with css class only, without explicit styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248542/jquery-animate-with-css-class-only-without-explicit-styles)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `transition` property in the CSS applied to element (`.nav`):

```
.nav {
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Or in `.darkHeader`:

```
.darkHeader {
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

I think that is better to apply this to original class (`.nav`).

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/9fbr320y/3/

Comment: i'm trying to do this by jquery.

Comment: Why you don't want to use CSS?, the transitions are much better than with jQuery.